# Innovative design solutions to increase recycling rates among university students

Tags: recycling

I have an assignment to research innovate design solutions to increase recycling rates, in particular recycling rates among university students.

I've found an excellent research report on topic (but no innovative design solutions), and an Australian university's report on their recycling program, which focused on things like adding recycling bins next to general waste bins, and other general strategies, but I am having trouble finding (or Googling) innovate design solutions.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I have seen this question before (but cannot find it). Was that on [opendata.se]? And shouldn't you just rephrase it to "How can I increase recycling rates among university students?". That seems to be what you want. BTW: recycling *of what* and *where*? Please [edit] your question.